# How to set up version control with Subversion, Ocaml, Emacs

Tags: svn, version-control, ocaml

We are 2 developers working on a project in Ocaml. It seems that version control with Subversion is useful and pratical. I would like to look for very basic and simple tools to use, could anyone tell me where to start? We are using Linux, I am using Ubuntu.

Thank you very much!

Edit 1: I code Ocaml under Emacs, so would prefer tools around that...

Comment: Do you mean setting up/configuring your IDE to use subversion or setting up your own Subversion server?

Comment: After installing __svn__ run __man svnadmin__ and __man svn__ on the console. Those two man-pages contain everything you need to set up and use a svn repository.

Comment: @idefix: I do not know if i need to set up my own server... We are 2 developers, at the moment, i develop the code on my side, I want him to share the code, and develop on his side with a version control...

Answer (score 5):

There's [a comparison of subversion clients here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients), but to be honest I find that command line svn works just fine, especially on linux. Windows users tend to prefer [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) which is really quite nice.

I'm sure you've already discovered the [free online book on subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) too.

Comment: There are too many clients, could anyone suggest a suitable one for Ocaml and Emacs?

Comment: Apparently emacs is supposed to contain a client?

Comment: In all honesty I don't think you need a client at all - as I said, svn from the command line works just fine.